# Android : ENOENT when I'm trying to save bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, io

I everyBody ,

When I am trying to save a bitmap that I had dowloaded on my smartphone I have this error:

```
09-26 16:10:46.981 11106-11106/woowin.woowin W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/6535-6234/saved_images/photo_profil.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

...
```

I download this picture to have a jpeg file in my profile, and I try to save it in a specific file. I use this class:

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage){
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls){

        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try{
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        saveImage(result,"photo_profil");
    }

}
private void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap, String image_name) {


    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String fname = image_name +".jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I searched on internet a response and I implemented the correct permission: 
    
Where is the problem ?

I need to save the picture on the local storage. And create a specific folder.
Thank's to reply